# How to play youtube videos in Android application？

Tags: youtube-data-api

I want to create an Android application and to play the newest youtube videos in my channel. 
1.Which API do I need to use, the Youtube Data API or the Android Player API? How are these two APIs used together?

In addition, I think the first to fetch a lot of videoIds of the Video through Data API by server side, and then push this videoIds to the client side(Android), then play the video by the Android Player API. I do not know if I understand right?

Comment: you need to implement youtube player API, try this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/

Comment: thanks，I saw it is only the user description of Android player API .Is that need youtube Data API?